# What is the fastest method to read STDIN data into console app with C++

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application, stdout, stdin

I have a console app written with C++ that needs to accept text input from another process via writeline (followed by a deadline.) I'm assuming that such needs to be done via STDIN, but it also needs to work in the fastest way possible. My console app then needs to reply to the process back.

I haven't done console programming for awhile now, but I remember from C classes at school that there's a lot of C-type functions, like `fgets`, `getline`, etc. but what I remember is that they seemed to be quite slow.

So is there any way to do this exchange (again, "quick in and then out") with WinAPIs?

Comment: I'm curious, why does it need to be as fast as possible? Anyway, I would avoid iostreams for this.

Comment: If you have access to both applications...why not **shared memory**? It's pretty fast (I didn't find it but I remember a nice answer about this topic here on SO).

Comment: @Pubby: For the performance of the process that calls it.

Comment: @Adriano: I do not have access to the source code of the calling process.

Comment: Before doing any rash optimization, you should measure and profile to see if this is the bottleneck you really think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest method in theory will almost certainly be the system
level input routines, since both the `stdin` (in C, but also
available in C++) and `std::cin` build on these.  On the other
hand, they have generally been optimized for the platform, so
unless you can find the optimal configuration yourself (e.g.
things like buffer size), you might not gain much, if anything:
calling `read` (Unix) or `ReadFile` (Windows) for each character
will probably be slower than using something like
`std::getline`.

The other question is what you plan on doing with the data after
you've read it.  Functions like `read` or `ReadLine` give you
a buffer (`char[]`) with a certain number of characters; you
then have to analyse it, break it into lines, etc.  Functions
like `std::getline` give you an `std::string` with the line in
it.  If you're a really skilled C++ programmer, you can probably
organize things so that the actual data are never moved from the
`char[]`, but this would require re-implementing a lot of things
that are already implemented in the standard library.  The use
of templates in the standard library means that you don't have
to implement nearly as much as you would have to otherwise, but
you'll still need to create an equivalent to `std::string` which
maintains two iterators (`char const*`) rather than the data
itself.

In the end, I'd start by writing the application using
`std::getline` and `std::string`.  Once it's working, I'd see
what its actual performance is, and only then, if necessary,
consider ways of improving it.